# Copying huge InnoDB table as a file?

Tags: mysql, innodb

We have a huge InnoDB table (**153G**) that we need to move to another server. We use **innodb_file_per_table**. Is there a way to copy just the **IBD** file somehow? How would target DB recognize the file and know about its metadata? 
If needed, we can stop the DB for the copying.

EDITED:
One of the big tables is this:

```
CREATE TABLE `140M_table` (
  `field1` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `field2` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `field3` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `field4` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `field5` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `field6` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `field7` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `field8` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `field9` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`field1`),
  KEY `captureDateIdx` (`field2`,`feild6`),
  KEY `personaSubIdx` (`field3`,`field6`,`field5`),
  KEY `FKE6B5072DF27AF1FE` (`field8`),
  KEY `FKE6B5072D54F7256A` (`field7`),
  KEY `temp_key_idx` (`field9`),
  CONSTRAINT `FKE6B5072D54F7256A` FOREIGN KEY (`field7`) REFERENCES `small_table`     (`field7`),
  CONSTRAINT `FKE6B5072DF27AF1FE` FOREIGN KEY (`field8`) REFERENCES `2M_table` (`field9`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=136181731 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: Why not temporarily set up async replication? That way you'll even get new and modified data while copying...

Comment: This is done for migration. We need to minimize the downtime window. Because of that we want to import big tables on separate machines and then combine them in one DB.

Comment: Which was the whole point of my question... you'd have a downtime of zero if you async replicate it.

Comment: We migrate from MS SQL server by exporting and importing gigantic CSV files. Because it takes too long to import a CSV, we thought of doing it in parallel, and then combining binary IDB files.

Comment: What part of importing your CSV takes so long?

Comment: @alain-collins: It seems that indexes are taking most of the time, because loading same table without the indexes is MUCH faster. We tried loading without indexes and then creating them, but it takes even longer. Therefore we want to load tables on separate machines and then combine them in one DB. But, i'm growing increasingly skeptical that it is possible...
i added one of the tables to the original post.

Comment: Use the partition of tables to backup and you can also use http://www.zmanda.com/index.html for mysqlbackup

Comment: @vineet1982, how will partition of tables help in moving them to another server?

Answer (score 3):

You can't just copy InnoDB tables. Even with innodb_file_per_table all InnoDB files share a central "cache" file (ibdata#, ib_logfile#), which are stored in the root level of the mysql data directory.

You need to copy ALL the InnoDB tables plus the shared cache files to the new server, or dump the table. Dumping the table can take quite a bit longer since you are "moving" the data 3 time (dump, copy, restore). Make sure your InnoDB settings in my.cnf are the same on both servers, otherwise you will get errors when you try to startup mysql on the new server.

Comment: That's what i thought, but the problem is what happens to ibdata, ib_logfile of the target environment. The idea was to load one big table on comp1, another big table on comp2, then move second table from comp2 to comp1. If we copy ibdata, ib_logfile, that would kill contents of comp1. Even if we move it to comp3, we cannot move both comp1 and comp2's ibdata and ib_logfile.

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to merge two systems. You can't do that with InnoDB tables. Dumping is really the only/quickest way. You can probably speed things up by nfs mounting comp1 on comp2 and dumping directly to the mount. Then you avoid a dump+copy.

Comment: @brent-baisley, if i to mysqldump, i need to load it, which is as slow as running LOAD DATA INFILE.

Comment: There aren't many options when it comes to InnoDB tables. You can speed up import by allocating a lot of memory to your key cache and sort buffers. It's index creation that usually slows things down. Change the values back to normal when you are done.

Comment: @brent-baisley, thanks for the info. I was just wondering what params set key cache and sort buffers for InnoDB. I found such params for MyISAM, but i'm not sure they apply to InnoDB.

Comment: sort_buffer_size is for any table type, myisam_sort_buffer_size is for MyISAM tables. innodb_buffer_pool_size is sort of your "key cache" for Innodb. Bumped that up for the import. What you are trying to do is avoid file sorting during index creation.

Comment: @brent-baisley, THANKS A LOT!  Changing sort_buffer_size seems to increase the import performance significantly. I need to do more tests, but preliminary results are very encouraging.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of partition the problem would be resolved as ubder:

```
CREATE TABLE test_part_innodb (c1 int default NULL, c2 varchar(30) default NULL, c3 date default NULL) engine=InnoDB
-> PARTITION BY RANGE (year(c3)) (PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (2000),
-> PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (2001) , PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN (2002) ,
-> PARTITION p3 VALUES LESS THAN (2003) , PARTITION p4 VALUES LESS THAN (2004) ,
-> PARTITION p5 VALUES LESS THAN (2005) , PARTITION p6 VALUES LESS THAN (2006) ,
-> PARTITION p7 VALUES LESS THAN (2007) , PARTITION p8 VALUES LESS THAN (2008) ,
-> PARTITION p9 VALUES LESS THAN (2009) , PARTITION p10 VALUES LESS THAN (2010),
-> PARTITION p99 VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.13 sec)



show create table test_part_innodb\G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
Table: test_part_innodb
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `test_part_innodb` (
`c1` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`c2` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
`c3` date DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
/*!50100 PARTITION BY RANGE (year(c3))
(PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (2000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (2001) ENGINE = InnoDB,
PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN (2002) ENGINE = InnoDB,
PARTITION p3 VALUES LESS THAN (2003) ENGINE = InnoDB,
PARTITION p4 VALUES LESS THAN (2004) ENGINE = InnoDB,
PARTITION p5 VALUES LESS THAN (2005) ENGINE = InnoDB,
PARTITION p6 VALUES LESS THAN (2006) ENGINE = InnoDB,
PARTITION p7 VALUES LESS THAN (2007) ENGINE = InnoDB,
PARTITION p8 VALUES LESS THAN (2008) ENGINE = InnoDB,
PARTITION p9 VALUES LESS THAN (2009) ENGINE = InnoDB,
PARTITION p10 VALUES LESS THAN (2010) ENGINE = InnoDB,
PARTITION p99 VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE ENGINE = InnoDB) */
1 row in set (0.00 sec)


delimiter //
CREATE PROCEDURE load_test_part_innodb()
begin
do
declare v int default 0;
while v do
insert into test_part_innodb
values (v,'testing partitions',adddate('2000-01-01',(rand(v)*36520) mod 3652));
set v = v + 1;
end while;
end
// 
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

delimiter ;
call load_test_part_innodb();
Query OK, 1 row affected (1 hour 11 min 25.19 sec)

select count(*) from test_part_innodb where c3 > date '2000-01-01' and c3 < date '2000-12-31';
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
| 99681 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.22 sec)


show create view part_backup\G;
    *************************** 1. row ***************************
    View: part_backup
    Create View: CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `part_backup` AS select

    concat('mysqldump',' -u root',' -p ',' --no-create-info',' --where="',(case `p2`.`PARTITION_METHOD` when 'hash' then
    concat(`p2`.`PARTITION_EXPRESSION`,' % ',(select count(0) from `information_schema`.`partitions` `p3` where ((`p3`.`TABLE_SCHEMA` =
    `p2`.`TABLE_SCHEMA`) and (`p3`.`TABLE_NAME` = `p2`.`TABLE_NAME`))),' = ',(`p2`.`PARTITION_ORDINAL_POSITION` - 1)) when 'list' then
    concat(`p2`.`PARTITION_EXPRESSION`,' in (',`p2`.`PARTITION_DESCRIPTION`,')') when 'range' then
    concat(if((`p2`.`PARTITION_ORDINAL_POSITION` = 1),'',concat(`p2`.`PARTITION_EXPRESSION`,' >=
    ',replace(`p1`.`PARTITION_DESCRIPTION`,'MAXVALUE',~(0)),' and ')),concat(`p2`.`PARTITION_EXPRESSION`,'
    ',`p2`.`TABLE_SCHEMA`,'.',`p2`.`TABLE_NAME`) AS `Name_exp_1` from (`information_schema`.`partitions` `p2` left join
    `information_schema`.`partitions` `p1` on(((`p1`.`TABLE_SCHEMA` = `p2`.`TABLE_SCHEMA`) and (`p1`.`TABLE_NAME` = `p2`.`TABLE_NAME`) and

    ((`p1`.`PARTITION_ORDINAL_POSITION` + 1) = `p2`.`PARTITION_ORDINAL_POSITION`)))) where ((`p2`.`TABLE_SCHEMA` = database()) and
    (`p2`.`PARTITION_METHOD` in ('hash','list','range')))
    character_set_client: utf8
    collation_connection: utf8_general_ci
    1 row in set (0.01 sec)

desc part_backup;
+------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Name_exp_1 | mediumtext | YES | | NULL | |
+------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)

select * from part_backup;
```

Comment: Thanks. This looks like an interesting solution, but it's somewhat complicated at the same time. Also, it seems to rely on mysqldump. Using mysqldump and then loading the dump, is as slow as just doing the LOAD DATA INFILE.

Comment: @Philopator This process is used where data is very large as in present case the Data is about 153GB and while doing through mysqldump have to write the data continually and if it take 1 minute to write 1 GB data it would take 153 which is around 2.5 hours another thing the database size is 153GB but the dump size would be atlest 160GB as adding of " and , Another thing how to carry the 153GB database, the only method is done through taking hard disk. But in this method fragments can be made and each fragment can be zipped which would reduce size about 50% and easily transfer the data

Comment: I think the problem would be in loading of mysqldump. That would take forever. But thanks for the idea.