# How can I recover currupt database in magento?

Tags: mysql, database, magento, innodb, recovery

I setup fresh xampp(latest version) and copy mysql/data folder from old xampp(little bit lower version).

When I am access my magento project database through phpmyadmin, i am shocked. Here only 19 tables listed.

I checked in mysql/data directory, database folder and files with tables name(*.frm) are exist.

Please let me know how can i get back my complete database?

PS: I am using window 7.

Comment: Why you dont just dump your old database in an sql format and restore that file instead of copy the whole directory?

Comment: Yes, you are right, but I realize this after this incident happen with me. What's now? Do you have any solution?

Comment: My solution is simple....remove your new xaamp installation, remove the folders, and install this again....make a sql dump from you old mysql database, and restore it in your new installation(use phpmyAdmin or HeidiSql)

Answer (score 1):

In Magento most of the tables are innodb (except for those 19 you found in your new installation). For innodb tables you cannot just copy the table files from the data folder. [See this for more explanations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6227473/2047249).
If you cannot create a dump of the old db and restore it in your new xampp it may be lost.

Comment: Thanks for your kind information, but now it's too late for this. can you please suggest me any solution on my current situation? When I browse database in sqlYog, it's listed all tables but not able to browse these tables. it's throw an error like "table not exist".

Answer (score 0):

When copying Magento Database, be sure to use "Single Transactions".  Otherwise, it will cause issues.

this is how I do it using command line:

1. Dump existing table into a file:

   mysqldump -u [YOUR USER] -p'[YOUR PASS]' --single-transaction --database [Your DB Name] > [FILE-NAME-TO-DUMP.sql]
2. Then copy the file to the server you want to create the database.
3. Create your database that you'll be using on the new server
4. Run the following

   cat [FILE-NAME-TO-DUMP.sql] | grep -vi "^USE" | grep -vi "^CREATE DATABASE" |  mysql -u [YOUR USER] -p'[YOUR PASS]' --database [Your DB Name]

Comment: useful information! but please suggest me any solution on my current situation? When I browse database in sqlYog, it's listed all tables but not able to browse these tables. it's throw an error like "table not exist".